# Spark filter out columns and create dataFrame with remaining columns and create dataFrame with filtered columns

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I am new to Spark.

I have loaded a CSV file into a Spark DataFrame, say OriginalDF

Now I want to 
1. filter out some columns from it and create a new dataframe of the originalDF 
2. create a dataFrame out of the extracted columns

How can these 2 dataframes be created in spark scala?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

using select, you can select what columns you want.

```
val df2 = OriginalDF.select($"col1",$"col2",$"col3")
```

using filter you should able to filter the rows.

```
val df3 = OriginalDF.where($"col1" < 10)
```

another way to filter data is using where. Both filter and where are synonyms so you can use them interchangeably.

```
val df3 = OriginalDF.filter($"col1" < 10)
```

Note select and filter returns a new dataframe as a result.

Comment: Thanks Naveen, Can you please show how can I use filter method instead of where clause?

Comment: Both `filter` and `where` are used to filter rows using the given condition. `where` is just an alias for `filter`.